# connection string issue in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, web-config

I am having a solution that has two projects - data access layer project and mvc project
In data access layer i m using entity framework. and there is a reference to data access layer in mvc project. Now when I run the mvc project it says connection string is not there but it is there in app.config of data access layer project. i tried to copy the connection string and put it in web.config of mvc project but again it was not able to find it.
So I gave absolute path of the folder containing csdl, ssdl and msl file from data access layer project to web.config. It is working now.
But I want to give a relative path. Please tell me how can I give relative path. I am using EF 6.
I tried ./ to the root and ~/ and ../ but nothing is working
Regards,
Manish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to copy the csdl, ssdl and msl file from bin of other project and paste it to the bin of start up project and then give reference to those files in connection string using ~\bin\

It will work.

Regards,
Manish

Answer (score 1):

Copy the connection string segment to your web.config file in the MVC project and it will work.

There is only one config file being read in your application, this is the one for the startup project. In this case is your web.config.